# Is it possible to create a WebLogic 12.x domain from the command line?

Tags: weblogic

Is is possible script the creation of a WebLogic 12.x domain in online mode? The docs and various blogs mention the ability to do so only in offline mode and/or to generate domain templates(my terminology might be a little off there) but that's not really useful as far as I can tell.

The preferred WSL scripting tool I've been investigating is WLST.

Thx!

Comment: Online mode requires the domain to be actually running, so it's not possible to create one this way.  For Offline mode your script/code needs to be able to access the file system of the server hosting the domain.  For Online, you'll need network access to the listen address of the Administration server of the domain.

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy. My expectation was that there is some sort of management API which could be leveraged to do the initial provisioning of the domain but your comment and my additional research agree that is not the case -- looks like filesystem + shelling out to a command line/jar is the only route to domain creation.